# What is the difference between introspection and retrospection?

Tags: meaning, differences

I want to know what is the exact difference between introspection and retrospection. I keep 
hearing words like self-introspection. What does that mean?

Can someone clarify with examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Introspection**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/introspection): Looking in at/into one's self.

[**Retrospection**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/retrospection?s=t): Looking back at/into the past.

Examples:

After some much-needed *introspection*, Joe finally realized the true reasons why he'd been so anxious lately.

The *retrospection* proved valuable for Sally who vowed to never again repeat the past and set a new course for the future.

'Self-retrospection' isn't frequently used in my experience as despite it typically involving one's own experiences, does not require the reflexiveness that 'self' imposes. Similarly, 'self-introspection' may not be any more descriptive than merely 'introspection' in many cases where it is commonly used.

Hope that helps!